# How can I get an image to be 100% width when there is a container set?

Tags: html, css, containers, background-image

```css
body {
  padding: 0 8%;
}

div {
  background-image: url(https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/content/images/2020/04/w-qjCHPZbeXCQ-unsplash.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  height: 350px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla consectetur risus et felis lobortis porttitor. Quisque faucibus lectus ac eros consectetur ultrices id vel lacus. Pellentesque efficitur nibh eget rhoncus volutpat. Sed risus arcu, tempor
    id dignissim nec, fringilla vel lectus. Sed pellentesque ipsum eget metus sodales dapibus. Proin mi metus, fermentum eget scelerisque non, suscipit vel sem. Aenean mattis mi nec odio eleifend dictum. Duis sed ex ut neque tincidunt vehicula. Suspendisse
    eget nisl dapibus lacus porttitor tristique. Maecenas pulvinar leo urna, et semper nulla tristique at. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut facilisis luctus sem.</p>
  <div>
    <div>

</body>
```

How can I make the background image in the empty `div` to be full `100% width` ? So it does ignore the `padding: 0 8%` that is set on the `<body>`

Comment: remove the padding and put the padding value as a margin on the child `p` element instead

Comment: You can add a negative Margin/Padding to the DIV so it will ignore the body-tag padding. But I'm not sure if this is the right way to do it.

Comment: This might help: https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/rNWWjXM?editors=1100

Comment: @Martin the padding on the <p> element is actually used on much more elements in the page so it needs to stay on the <body> tag

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal See my answer above ^

Comment: @Panic You can use classes, [Check This, I have updated the code](https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/rNWWjXM?editors=1100)

Answer (score 0):

Use negative margin:

```css
body {
  padding: 0 8%;
  margin:0;
}

div {
  background-image: url(https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/content/images/2020/04/w-qjCHPZbeXCQ-unsplash.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  height: 350px;
  margin: 0 -9.52%;
  
  /* 9.52 = ((100/(1 - 2*0.08) - 100)/2 
                           ^-- your padding
  */
}
```

```html
<body>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla consectetur risus et felis lobortis porttitor. Quisque faucibus lectus ac eros consectetur ultrices id vel lacus. Pellentesque efficitur nibh eget rhoncus volutpat. Sed risus arcu, tempor
    id dignissim nec, fringilla vel lectus. Sed pellentesque ipsum eget metus sodales dapibus. Proin mi metus, fermentum eget scelerisque non, suscipit vel sem. Aenean mattis mi nec odio eleifend dictum. Duis sed ex ut neque tincidunt vehicula. Suspendisse
    eget nisl dapibus lacus porttitor tristique. Maecenas pulvinar leo urna, et semper nulla tristique at. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Ut facilisis luctus sem.</p>
  <div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
Set the vertical-align property to middle to vertically center the image element in the containing <div> . Set the background-size property to 100% so our image fills the image element. Set the background-position property to 50% 50% to align the background image within the image element
```